# VPN PPTP Limitations with Azure Virtual Machines

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, vpn, azure-virtual-machine, pptp

We're evaluating Azure Virtual Machines for a data warehousing project and have found that it doesn't support PPTP VPN connecting from the VM to an on-premise network.

We need to connect to an on-premise source SQL server that's behind an older router and have found that if it's not an Azure supported router, it won't work.  Additionally, Azure's Virtual Network functionality took a day just to decipher.

We'd expect simple VPN functionality from the VM to work, but apparently Microsoft is blocking the required protocols so that Virtual Networking has to be used.

This configuration works fine from EC2 and even from my laptop.  We would have preferred Azure since we have a SQL server architecture, though if this limitation is true, we'll have to move to EC2 from Azure.

Has anyone run into this or can someone confirm there is no workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Point-to-Site VPN instead of a Site-to-Site one.  A P-t-S doesn't require a hardware device and can be achieved using a local Windows Server.  Setup steps here: [on MSDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/)

Comment: Thank you - we had considered PTS but weren't comfortable using it yet in a production environment.

Comment: VPN is really the best interconnect technique you have to hand - if it doesn't work for you then perhaps AWS is a better choice.  I would temper that statement though with the understanding that site-to-site VPN in Azure has redundant cloud hosts so your Azure connectivity is highly available.  Building the same in AWS will incur additional instance run costs.